# Render page breaks in DevExpress RichTextEdit

Tags: devexpress, richedit-control

I want to be able to add and remove page-breaks to a `RichEditControl` element.

I understand that it's possible to add the page break by pressing Ctrl + Enter, but it's impossible for the user to see the page break and remove it, as it currently looks like it's a simple new line.

I tried to use the `DXRichEditFormattingMarkVisibilityOptions` to display a separator, thinking it would display the page break, without luck:

```
<d:RichEditControl ActiveViewType="Simple"
                   ShowBorder="False" Background="{x:Null}"
                   AutoSizeMode="Vertical" LayoutUnit="Document"
                   CommandBarStyle="Empty" BarManager="{TemplateBinding BarManager}">
    <d:RichEditControl.FormattingMarkVisibilityOptions>
        <d:DXRichEditFormattingMarkVisibilityOptions Separator="Visible"/>
    </d:RichEditControl.FormattingMarkVisibilityOptions>
</d:RichEditControl>
```

Is there any way to render the page break in the `RichEditControl` and let it be easy to be removed by the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the `Page Break` character, you need to execute a command that display all hidden characters (such as paragraphs, spaces and tabs) and force these other characters to be hidden back, letting just the page break being displayed.

```
var command = new ToggleShowWhitespaceCommand(_richEditControl);
command.Execute();
```

Then you can apply this to the style of the control or alter directly via code:

```
<d:RichEditControl.FormattingMarkVisibilityOptions>
    <d:DXRichEditFormattingMarkVisibilityOptions HiddenText="Hidden" 
        ParagraphMark="Hidden" Space="Hidden" TabCharacter="Hidden"/>
</d:RichEditControl.FormattingMarkVisibilityOptions>
```